# finding all tags in XML and their positions

Tags: php, regex, tags

Is it possible to find all tags in string with their positions?

For example for following text:

```
#$text = file_get_contents($file); # for the simplicity - see other line:
$text = "<tag> sometext <tag2> more text </tag2>";
```

in the result i would like to get all tags from `$text` and their positions:

```
 - [0] name = <tag>, position = 1

 - [1] name = <tag2>, position = X

 - [2] name = </tag2>, position = X
```

As I understand - a regex shall be used. If it helps - I know the names of all tags. For the simplicity here they are:

```
<tag>, <tag1>, <tag2>, <tag3>, </tag>, </tag1>, </tag2>, </tag3>
```

What's the best approach to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex:

```
preg_match_all('@(\</?[a-z0-9]+\>)@', $text, $m);

$tags = array();
foreach ($m[1] as $i => $match) {
  echo "name = " . $m[1][$i] . ", position = " . ($i+1) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: getting an error:
Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 13 in C:\php\www\fetchxml2.php on line 66

Comment: One bracket was misplaced, fixed now, sorry

Comment: one more fix to match tags with numeric characters.. sorry for the inconvenience (this time I executed&verified the code)

Comment: for some reason I am getting: "name = , position = 1
name = , position = 2
name = , position = 3".. i.e. there are no tag names and positions are basically iterations of integer..

Comment: This was meant to be run on command line, you cannot see the tags & newlines on browser. try viewing page source. If you need to render them on browser, you need to replace `"\n"` with `<br />` and `$m[1][$i]` with `htmlentities($m[1][$i])`

Comment: that did the trick! What about positions of tags within the string? i.e. they should be similar to these: 1, 14, 25..

Comment: You can see their positions as 1,2,3.. What do you mean by position? do you mean which character they are starting from?

Comment: exactly, not the position in array, but the position in a string. Sorry for confusion

Comment: that is a bit tricky. First, initialize an `$offset` variable to zero before foreach block. Then calculate `$pos` inside foreach block as `strpos($text, $m[1][$i], $offset)`, then replace `$i+1` with `$pos` and increment `$offset` by `$pos`